# Review indicator flag showing (orange) but no reviews pending

Tags: support, bug, edits

Screenshot below but the gist is that I'm seeing the flag but no edits seem to be pending.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The review indicator is a global indicator. Every user with review privileges sees the same number in the indicator. You have already reviewed these 5 items, but there are still other people who have to review them, so the indicator is still there.

Comment: Ah - a bit unintuitive in my opinion but thanks for at least clearing that up. So I have to know to keep checking it if the number changes from 5 to see what new ones I have not looked at?

Comment: @Skram Yes, you will have to keep checking if the number changes. For example, if it jumps from 5 to 4, it could be that one item has been reviewed and that there are no new items, but it could also mean that 2 items are reviewed and that there is a new item for you to review.